# Updating a javascript value from a php script

Tags: javascript, php, variables, setinterval

I have this code:

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 5000);
function myCallback() {
  g.refresh(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1), 100);
}
```

and it's working fine. Every 5 seconds I get a new random value.

I'd like to take the random value from a php script so I changed the code to:

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 5000);
function myCallback() {
  g.refresh(<?php echo $rand(1,100)?>);
}
```

but this code is executed only once, after5 seconds than I get non more new values... (or the returned random value is always the same?).

Why?
Thank you!

Comment: JavaScript has
 its own ways to get Random Number..

Comment: "but this code is executed only once" - that is correct. The webserver gets a http request, executes the php script and only the repsonse is sent back to client, i.e. when the javascript is executed the php instance that has served the html document containing the js code is long done, shut down and garbage collected. php->server-side, javascript->client-side and they are only connected by http requests.

Comment: I know, I'm using it in the first code and it's working. But this is just an exeample. I'd like to execute a php code here (or, better, get the value from a remote file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a PHP code that return a random value. In this page just "echo" a random value. Then, you make an Ajax request to get the value:

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 5000);
function myCallback() {
  $.ajax({
    url: random.php,
  }).done(function(data) {
    g.refresh(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: Just a comment. In this example, I make the ajax request using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Ajax to "ask" the next value to a php script.

Php only generate the page (and here a part of the javascript), but if you look at the source code of the rendered page (ctrl +u in mozilla), you will see :

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 5000);
function myCallback() {
   g.refresh(123);
}
```

where '123' is the value generated the first time.